# Why can't my socket retrieve text from a webpage?

Tags: python, sockets

Just started Learning socket programming, made a basic socket that in theory could connect to a website and read me the text off a txt  file.

```
msock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
msock.connect(('data.pr4e.org',80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/authors.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()
msock.send(cmd)

while True:
    dat = msock.recv(512)
    if len(dat) < 1:
        break
    print(dat.decode())
msock.close()
```

Instead of getting the block of text from the txt file on the site printed  I instead get this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at do1.dr-chuck.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

How do I fix this?

I tried this with multiple other txt files on other websites and still get a similar result. Tried other ports as well, but no luck.

Comment: A GET request does not contain the full URI, just the path. Also additional headers like `Host` maybe needed.

Comment: Also need `\r\n` not just `\n`, and  `GET /authors.txt` wasn't found but `GET /` was.

Comment: `http://data.pr4e.org/` should not be included in the request

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly not an expert on the HTTP protocol. However, adding `\r` and using raw bytes instead of a string seems to work:

```py
import socket

msock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
msock.connect(("data.pr4e.org", 80))
cmd = b"GET http://data.pr4e.org/authors.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
msock.send(cmd)

alldata = bytearray()
while True:
    dat = msock.recv(512)
    if len(dat) < 1:
        break
    alldata.extend(dat)
msock.close()
print(alldata.decode())
```

```
$ python3 tmp.py
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
... more lines ...
Korean,Victor (Kwangchun) Lee (이광춘)
```

Comment: @pythonnoob4567, if you like this answer, please accept and upvote it so my StackOverflow points increase :D

Comment: I would but I'm new and dont have enough reputation. Thanks again!